# Add the current url dynamic paramater into a jQuery script

Tags: jquery, url

Can I update the below jQuery code with the current url parameter? The parameters are changed each time.

```
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php?id=value&id2=value2 #hotel-list> *");
```

where this values are changed each time `?id=value&id2=value2`

As example:

On the page 1 - Main Page where I have the below code, the url param is :

```
?DesinationId=BO9B&roomsno=1&city=Barcelona&In=2015-05-01&Out=2015-05-08&rooms%5B0%5D%5Badult%5D=2&rooms%5B0%5D%5Bchild%5D=0
```

I need to send the same param to Rezults2 page when I try to pull its data.

The name id`s from the URL are always the same but their values are changed each time.

Comment: it a div id from thate current page and a div id from the page from where i pull its content (Rezults2.php )

Comment: Your data string value is in your page (page element) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question:

*Can I update the below jQuery code with the current url parameter?*

So I guess you want to get the location's search.

Try this:

```
var datastring = window.location.search; // now you can update this var and use
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php"+ datastring + " #hotel-list> *");
```

Maybe you want to use and append a var then:

```
var datastring = "?id=value&id2=value2"; // now you can update this var and use
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php"+ datastring + " #hotel-list> *");
```

If you go to the documentation of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) then you can find this:

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

You can see that you can send data object too. So even you can try sending like this too:

```
var datastring = {id : value, id2 : value2}; // now you can update this var and use
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php  #hotel-list> *", datastring);
```

Comment: have any odeea on how to get the full url param to update the datastring dynamic ?

Comment: are you looking for `location.pathname`?

Comment: check my question body.

Comment: @em0tic0n i guess you would like to use `window.location.search` then. check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameter of data to the server,

```
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php #hotel-list > *", { "id": value, "id2": value });
```

View this [**$.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) doc

---

You can also do something like this,

```
var data = "?id=" + value + "&id2=" + value2;
var url = "Rezults2.php?" + data + " #hotel-list > *";

$("#hotel-list").load(url);
```